# Duplicate record in db with Json Create Action Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to correct a duplicate record problem, when I create a new record, with a Json Create action.

Json script on my view

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/Panels/CreateNewAlert',
    dataType:'json';
    type:'post',
    contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    data:JSON.stringify({
        alertMap:{AlertModeID:$('#AlertModeID').val(),AlertPriorityID:$('#AlertPriorityID').val()},
        alertLog:{AlertTitle:$('#AlertLog_AlertTitle').val(),AlertText:$('#AlertLog_AlertText').val(),AlertStartDate:$('#AlertLog_AlertStartDate').val(),AlertActive:'true'},
        recipientlistip:brutelistip,
        recipientlistpc:brutelistpc
    }),
    async:true,
    processData:false,
    cache:false,
    succes:function(data){
        alert(data);
     },
    error:function(xhr){
        alert('error');
     }
})
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateNewAlert(AlertMap alertMap, AlertLog alertLog, RecipientMap recipientMap, int[] recipientlistip, int[] recipientlistpc)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
   db.AlertLog.Add(alertLog);
   db.SaveChanges();

   int alertid = alertLog.AlertID;
   recipientMap.IPgroupID = 3;
   recipientMap.AlertID = alertid;
   db.RecipientMap.Add(recipientMap);
   db.SaveChanges();

   alertMap.AlertID=alertid;
   alertMap.UsersID= User.Identity.GetUserId();
   db.AlertMap.Add(alertMap);
   db.SaveChanges();
   }
   return Json("Succes!");
}
```

I don't understand why alertLog is recorded twice, with two different id. alertMap and recipientMap are recorded with no duplicate.

I have checked with VS debug and `db.SaveChanges()` for alertLog, is only executed one time. I have tried a test :

```
alertLog.AlertActive = true;
alertLog.AlertTitle = "pif";
alertLog.AlertText = "pof";
alertLog.AlertStartDate = DateTime.Now;
alertLog.AlertEndDate = DateTime.Now;
db.AlertLog.Add(alertLog);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I have added data directly in the controller... and there is no duplicate. Maybe is my Json syntax which is incorrect... Is there another test that I could do ?
Thanks

EDIT : I think this a problem with the AlertID Foreign Key. AlertID is on AlertLog table, as the primary key with identity increment. I have a reference to AlertID in my RecipientMap as Foreign Key. When a user write a DeskAlert he choose a list of recipient for this alert (IP group or/and pc group). So RecipientMap table could like that:

```
|ID(Pk)|IPgroupID(fk)|PCgroupID(fk)|AlertID(fk)|
|------|-------------|-------------|-----------|
| 1    |   1         |  null       |   15      |
| 2    |   1         |  null       |   15      |
| 3    |   2         |  1          |   16      |
```

I think my problem is AlertID Foreign Key is not well configurated

EDIT 2 : Ok this is the last step.

There is a last thing, that I don't understand. It's about how to add a list in my datatable. I'm trying to use a list, but, I missed something.

```
var AL = new AlertLog()
{..};
var IPlist = new List<RecipientMap>();
var rp = new RecipientMap();
foreach (int ipid in recipientlistip)
{
    RM.IPgroupID = ipid;
}
IPlist.Add(rp);
AL.RecipientMap.AddRange(IPlist);
```

With the last line I get this error on AddRange `"System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WebAppDev.RecipientMap> does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WebAppDev.RecipientMap> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`

In my model class file IPgroupID and PCgroupID are :

```
public Nullable<int>IPgroupID {get;set;}
public Nullable<int>PCgroupID {get;set;}
```

AND THE SOLUTION !
Yes It's worked ! In my controller I've made this (for one list) :

```
List<RecipientMap>IPlist= new List<RecipientMap>();
for (int i = 0;i<recipientlistip.Length;i++){
    IPlist.Add(new RecipientMap
    {
        IPgroupID = recipientlistip[i]
    });
}
AL.RecipientMap.AddRange(IPlist);
```

But I've also added an ExtensionMethods for using AddRange with ICollection. That's why it's didn't work at the begining. Thanks you very much for your help !

Comment: Is this a problem in the database or entity framework setup? ForeignKeys? Triggers? Your client side and controller code looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds that you have one master (AlertLog) and two details (RecipientMap, AlertMap). check this out, if you've set relations in SQL Server:

```
  // create Master
  var AL = new AlertLog() 
{ AlertModeID = alertLog.AlertModeID, AlertPriorityID = alertLog.AlertPriorityID};

  // create Details
  var RM = new RecipientMap() { .. = ...}; // Do NOT consider FK here!
  var AM = new AlertMap() { .. = ... }; // Do NOT consider FK here!

  // add Details to Master
  AL.RecipentMaps.Add(RM); // FK is automatically set here
  AL.AlertMaps.Add(AM); // FK is automatically set here

  db.AlertLog.Add(AL); // add Master
  db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I've tried this sample and it's works for set FK automatically. But I have one more question : in RecipientMap table, how I could insert my array of ID ? for example if I need to insert all of ID's in int[] recipientlistip with the same AlertID, how I could do that ?

Comment: you might want to create a `List<RecipientMap>` with desired ID set, and use `AL.RecipientMaps.AddRange( /* List of your RecipientMap */ )`. Also, if you've set auto increment ID for RecipientMap, there is no need to consider IDs at all, just add new instances in a `List<RecipientMap>`. @mrplume

Comment: Ok, I've tried that solution, but there is something I don't understand, I've made an edit.

Comment: so another answer is needed to complete your inquiry. @mrplume

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are using the latest `EF 6.1.3`, secondly, you might need to combine this answer with previous one.

So, there is a `List<RecipientMap>` like follows:

```
int ipGroupID = // something you know how to find

var RM1 = new RecipientMap(){IPgroupID = ipGroupID, ..};
var RM2 = new RecipientMap(){IPgroupID = ipGroupID, ..};
var RM3 = new RecipientMap(){IPgroupID = ipGroupID, ..};

var listRM = new List<RecipientMap>(){RM1, RM2, RM3};
```

then, instead of `AL.RecipentMaps.Add(RM)` you'll need `AL.RecipentMaps.AddRange(listRM)` and save the changes to `db`. This way, `AlertLog`'s FK is automatically set, and the `IPgroupID` is previously set to the list of `RecipientMap`.

Answer (score -1):

In some cases working with JQuery, programmers might accidentally set two event handlers for Submit! check this matter out, whether you have "onClick" alongside your JQuery handler or not?

Comment: I think this is a problem of Foreign Key. In AlertLog table AlertID is unique Primary Key. I have a reference in RecipientMap to AlertID as Foreign Key. RecipientMap recorded group which can see the Alert. So one, two or more group could be linked to the same AlertID. This Foreign Key must be not configurated correctly

Comment: @mrplume simply your code sounds normal, and EF is not about to malfunction on such code! for the record, try ONE db.SaveChanges() in the end. also you can try something else...